# HTML/ Javascript onchange won't work

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

This is my first question on stackoverflow.

I have a form:

```
 <input type="text" id="naam" onchange="naam()" name="toevoegerNaam_1"
placeholder="Uw naam" />
```

It's a very large form, and this is the specific code.
You see the `onchange="naam()"`

This is the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function naam(){
    alert("test");

    }

</script>
```

This won't work!

If I do this: onchange="alert('test');" , it works fine.

And i can call the function with onclick.

I don't understand what's wrong.

Please help me! Maybe someno saw that I'm Dutch (Belgium), so sorry for my bad English, I will edit it, if my question isn't clear enough.

Comment: any errors shown in the console?
try to take an other name for the function than for the id. (I think I can remember a moment I had the same problem)

Comment: Where is the script tag located? In the header or after the form?

Comment: try `naam = function()` instead of `function naam()`. This will force it into the global scope, which is most likely your issue

Comment: +1 check console for error because its working fine here (using chrome), also tell us the browser

Comment: When I change the content and tab out I am getting the alert on chrome and IE. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Thanks, eclipse (my IDE) give no errors. I'm testing it in on chrome(and chromium), firefox, opera and IE. On all the browsers there  is the same problem. The javascript code is below the form. I will try the tips!

Comment: Thanks! It works fine! I changed the name and it works. I also can load the value of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

**try using onkeyup/onkeydown** for the function to execute as soon as you press the key,

because onchange will execute only when the **focus from input field is changed/moved**.